# How single page HTML site without any CMS

Tags: html

I want to make a single page HTML site. I have made the template, but I wanted to know how to make it go live on my hosting.

I have tried many things but none of them work, I don't want to use any CMS, just a plain and simple HTML site. I have both a domain and hosting.

Comment: your file name must be index.html and upload it to root directory or you can say folder with domain name that must be root folder

Comment: use filezilla and login with your ftp credewntial like host username and password and port may be 21 or 22

Comment: It depends entirely what what methods your hosting service provides. Consult their documentation.

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed — "your file name must be index.html" — That depends on the server configuration.

Comment: "upload it to root directory" — How do they know what directory that is?

Comment: "or you can say folder with domain name" — That depends on the server configuration.

Comment: "use filezilla and login with your ftp" — That only works if the host provides FTP access. Mine doesn't. FTP is awful.

Answer (score -1):

If as "template" you mean HTML file than you should name your file as index.html and upload it via FTP to the work directory of your hosting server.